# What is the correct way to represent dates in a graph database (Neo4j)?

Tags: neo4j

CREATE(:People{name: "Sally", date_of_birth:"12-04-1991"})
I'm confused as to how to find her current age. Is my way of representing a date wrong?

Answer (score 2):

best way is to use the neo4j date / time format : https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/temporal/

But this should do it, given the date format that you use:

```
MATCH (p:People {name:"Sally"})
WITH p.date_of_birth AS date_of_birth ,date() AS now
// convert the stringDate into a date in the datetime format
WITH   now,
       date(
            {year:toInteger(right(date_of_birth,4)), 
             month:toInteger(substring(date_of_birth,3,2)), 
             day: toInteger(left(date_of_birth,2))
            }) AS date_of_birth 
RETURN duration.between(dateOfBirth,now).years AS age
```